# How can I find index of an object where key is a specific value?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hopefully I'm saying this properly...

How could I find the index of where ID = 68?

I need help creating a function that would return the index of 2... Thanks!

```
$posts = Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 20
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_content] => 
            [post_title] => Carol Anshaw
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 21
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_content] => 
            [post_title] => Marie Arana
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 68
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_content] => 
            [post_title] => T.C. Boyle
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 1395
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_content] => 
            [post_title] => Rosellen Brown
        )
)
```

Comment: Could this be `$index = $posts[2]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Make a trivial function** that iterates over the array
2. **Encapsulate it** instead of leaving it hanging
3. **Remember to use [var_export](http://php.net/var_export)** rather than print_r when pasting data structures for the community

You could make such a trivial function:

```
function getKeyForId($id, $haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if ($value->ID == $id) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
}

$keyFor68 = getKeyForId(68, $posts);
```

But it doesn't make sense to leave specific functions hanging. You could use [ArrayObject](http://php.net/arrayobject) as such:

```
class Posts extends ArrayObject {
    public function getKeyForId($id) {
        foreach($this as $key => $value) {
            if ($value->ID == $id) {
                return $key;
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Example usage:

```
$posts = new Posts();

$posts[] = new StdClass();
$posts[0]->ID = 1;
$posts[0]->post_title = 'foo';


$posts[] = new StdClass();
$posts[1]->ID = 68;
$posts[1]->post_title = 'bar';


$posts[] = new StdClass();
$posts[2]->ID = 123;
$posts[2]->post_title = 'test';

echo "key for post 68: ";
echo $posts->getKeyForId(68);
echo "\n";
var_export($posts[$posts->getKeyForId(68)]);
```

Output:

```
key for post 68: 1
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'ID' => 68,
   'post_title' => 'bar',
))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findIndexById($id, $array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if($value->ID == $id) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and you can search it like this `findIndexById(68, $array);` this will return you the index of array if it finds otherwise false.